# An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details - ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I am using entity framework 6 with asp.net mvc 5 and while inserting new record to the database the SaveChanges() method gives the subjected error which can be seen in the below image as well:

[image]

I googled a lot and did some workaround but nothing worked, below is my create action:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(ImagesVM img, HttpPostedFileBase upload)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var filename = "";
            var path = "";
            //var originalFilename = ""; 

            if (upload != null && upload.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                //originalFilename = Path.GetFileName(upload.FileName);
                if (!Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/Views/Images/Photots/" + img.PlayerId)))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath("~/Views/Images/Photots/" + img.PlayerId));
                }
                filename = img.PlayerId.ToString() + "_" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                path = Server.MapPath("~/Views/Images/Photots/" + filename);
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("error", "There was an error with saving the record");
                img.Players = new SelectList(db.Players, "Id", "Name");
                return View(img);
            }

            upload.SaveAs(path);
            ImageDTO dto = new ImageDTO();
            dto.ImageName = filename;
            dto.ImageUrl = path;
            dto.ThumbnailTitle = img.ThumbnailTitle;
            dto.ThumbnailDetails = img.ThumbnailDetails;
            dto.PlayerId = img.PlayerId;
            db.Images.Add(dto);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        img.Players = new SelectList(db.Players, "Id", "Name");
        return View(img);

    }
```

Any help is highly appreciated in advance.

Comment: check allowed the length of fields in db and length of saved strings. Most likely it is `path` value are too long

Comment: It's exactly what the error is saying, one of the fields you're trying to save is longer than the db column it's going into. Check them one by one.

Comment: The exception would suggest that you are trying to insert some text in a column and your text might be too long. You might check your table to see how long the fields can be. Then you can truncate the data yourself and you would not get the exception.

Comment: Thanks everyone, the issue was that the database column length was less than the value which was being passed to it.